# Retrieve and Store Images

Tags: android, performance

I have over 1000 images in my `drawable`.

Everytime I run my app the app it is very slow and is getting the following output:
`I/Choreographer: Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.`

I was wondering if there is any better way to store over 1000 images and retrieve them in my app as I've tried the following below?

I know you can have a database and retrieve each image. But I read that using a database is not suitable as it will lower efficiency.

I've tried moving the images to `drawable-xxxhdpi` folder but this did not change the outcome or effect the efficiency of the app.

I've also tried moving the images to the `mipmap` folder but this did not change the outcome.

I also read that you can create an `assets` folder and retrieve the images that way.

Any solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post some code? how are you loading the images? you will most likely need to be doing most of the work on a background thread

Comment: try to minimize image size as possible.. instead of images in any format try to use vector drawable images

Comment: Nothing you've written makes me assume that's the reason your app is slow.  You could be doing anything on the main thread to slow it.  Use a CPU profiler and figure out what you're actually spending your time on.

Comment: 1,000 images? why is this on the local device?